# Yii2 Modules and configuration

Tags: php, module, yii2

I'm not 100% sure that a module is the right way to go here. So thought i'd ask. My use case is that I have a fairly large application that is powered from an oracle DB.

We also have another DB which isn't oracle and would be involved in a different type of work and a different user group, so I thought I should use a module - Is that right? If not what's the best way to achieve do this kind of set up?

If so, is there a way to configure this second DB within my Module or should it be done within the main app/config/dp.php file?

Comment: You are using Basic or Advanced Application?

Comment: @NanaPartykar Basic

Comment: Then, create one more **db1.php** and include in `config/web.php` like as it is declared in **web.php** i.e. `'db1' => require(__DIR__ . '/db1.php'),`

Comment: But I'm ok to keep a module?

Comment: See. I don't know which module you are talking of.

Comment: I'm creating a module http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-modules.html

Comment: Ok. Ok. Yes. *It is OK*. @Jonny Brother

Comment: Thanks, if you sum this up in an answer i'll mark it correct

Comment: Sorry for answering late. I've written my answer. Below all answers are same @Jonny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you are using **Yii2-Basic Application**. So, Directory structure is like.

```
Root Folder
    -> assets
    -> commands
    -> components
    -> config
        -> console.php
        -> db.php
        -> params.php
        -> web.php
    -> controllers
    -> mail
    .
    .
    .
```

Your database connection details are present in **db.php**. Now, you want another Database to play important rle in your application. No worries. Create one more database connection details in,say, **db2.php** inside `config` folder.

**db2.php**

```
<?php

return [
  'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
  'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=another_database_name',
  'username' => 'username',
  'password' => 'password',
  'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

So, now directory structure will be :

```
Root Folder
    -> assets
    -> commands
    -> components
    -> config
        -> console.php
        -> db.php
        -> db2.php
        -> params.php
        -> web.php
    -> controllers
    -> mail
    .
    .
    .
```

Now, next step to include **db2.php** in the application.

Open **web.php**. Add one more line for `db2.php`

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'components' => [
        .
        .
        .
        'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
        'db2' => require(__DIR__ . '/db2.php'),
    ],
];
```

So, Another database connection is also set successfully. Now, next step is to use query related to another database connection.

```
$row = Yii::$app->db2->createCommand("SELECT * FROM `table_name`")->queryOne();
```

Answer (score 1):

In config/web.php add your second database configuration, create a file called db2.php and call it

```
'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),    
'db2' => require(__DIR__ . '/db2.php'),
```

in the model,

```
 class MyModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {

   // add the function below:
   public static function getDb() {
       return Yii::$app->get('db2'); // second database
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is define  two different component one of each db eg db1 for oracle and db2 for mysql in you config/web.php

```
'components' => [
    ......
    'db1' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'oci:dbname=//localhost:1521/mydatabase',
        'username' => 'scott',
        'password' => 'tiger',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
    'db2' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydbname',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ],
```

and the refer to Yii::$app->db1 or Yii::$app->db2 eg:

```
$count1 = Yii::$app->db1->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post')
         ->queryScalar();
```

or

```
$count2 = Yii::$app->db2->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM post')
         ->queryScalar();
```